# All the parallel to X-axis lines form a subbasis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, determine the open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Exercise**: Let $S$ be the collection of all straight lines in the plane which are parallel to the $X$-axis. If $S$ is a sub basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, describe the open sets in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$.

My attempt: If the lines were not parallel to the $X$-axis, every point (a,b) would be the intersection of two lines with different slope, then we would have the discrete topology. 
Since the slope is the same:

If $(x,y)\in A$, then $(x,y)\in A\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. So the open set $\mathbb{R}\times B$ where $B\subset\mathbb{R}$.

**Questions:**

**1**) How do I proceed to describe the open sets?

**2**)How do I prove $\mathbb{B}\times\mathbb{R}$ is open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subbase generated by the lines $L_y:= \mathbb{R} \times \{y\}$ generates a base of its topology by taking all finite intersections. But all of these are empty (for two different sets) so the subbase $\{L_y: y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is already a base.

This means that all open sets are unions of these sets if $O = \bigcup \{L_y: y \in B\}$ for some set $B$ then in fact $O = \mathbb{R} \times B$. So the topology 
generated is

$$\mathcal{T}= \{ \mathbb{R} \times B: B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$$ where $B$ ranges over all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

It follows that no set of the form $B \times \mathbb{R}$ is open, unless $B = \mathbb{R}$ or $B = \emptyset$, when we get the open set $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\emptyset$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just one question I would hope you could answer. How is it proven that $B\times\mathbb{R}$ is not open?

Comment: @PedroGomes 1. It's not of the form $\mathbb{R} \times B$ 2. It does not contain any $L_y$ when $B \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The topology consists of all possible unions of lines parallel to x-axis. If $B \subset \mathbb  R$ then $B \times \mathbb  R$ is not necessarily open in this space. In particular, $(0,1) \times \mathbb  R$ is not open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there I was thinking of $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ so that $B\times\mathbb{R}$ is a union of diferent points $a_1\times\mathbb{R}\cup a_2\times\mathbb{R}\cup...\cup a_n\times\mathbb{R}\subset B$. How should I then answer the question?